# Python Slice Ndarray with in Panda column based on segment location from Other columns

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, slice

I have a pandas dataframe with an 2d array stored in one of the columns: "mels"
In other columns of the Dataframe I have start and end location of columns I will like to extract from 2d array 'mels'.
Here is how my Dataframe looks like:

```
## Data Frame which has Start Location of a segment : HS_Start 
## & end location of a segment : HS_End
df_sound_loc.ix[:,-3:].head(5)[enter image description here][1]
```

HS_Start | HS_End | mels   |
---------| -------|-------
---13    | ---25  | [[0.0752865622903, 0.00439239454838, 0.0182232... |

**For Example HS_Start: 13 and HS_End is 25, then I am expecting all rows with 13 to 25 column values from respective "mels" array:
mels[:,13:25]**

so on and so forth for all rows

```
# Column mels is a 2D array of 128 rows and 680 columns
df_sound_loc.ix[1,-1].shape
```

> ```
> (128,680)
> ```

**Want to extract only the  Columns from mels: 2d array between  HS_Start & HS_End numbers**

```
print(df_sound_loc['mels'][:,df_sound_loc['HS_Start']:df_sound_loc['HS_End']])
```

Got following error:

**If key is contained, would have returned by now**

> ```
> ValueError: Can only tuple-index with a MultiIndex
> ```

I am new to Python and Dataframe operations. please advise

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: HS_Start HS_End mels
0 13 25 [[0.0752865622903, 0.00439239454838, 0.0182232...
1 34 46 [[0.0752865622903, 0.00439239454838, 0.0182232...
2 62 74 [[0.0752865622903, 0.00439239454838, 0.0182232...
3 86 98 [[0.0752865622903, 0.00439239454838, 0.0182232...
4 117 129 [[0.0752865622903, 0.00439239454838, 0.0182232...

Comment: Please edit question with data.

Comment: Also the best is create desired output.

Comment: @jezrael added data example and desired outcome.

Comment: Is possible use `df1['new'] = df1.apply(lambda x:  x['mels'][:, x['HS_Start']:x['HS_End']].tolist(),axis=1)` ?

Comment: @jezrael Thanks for the input, works like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1` for process by rows:

```
df1['new'] = df1.apply(lambda x: x['mels'][:, x['HS_Start']:x['HS_End']].tolist(),axis=1)
```